# Active directory syncronization

Tags: active-directory

I have a situation. how to synchronize active directoy created in one VM with, the active directory created on another VM, lying in the same network. VMs are in azure. It has nothing to do with Azure active directory.
simple purpose is to replicate and synchronize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got a way to achieve this.
Create two Vnets in azure. Make sure their IP ranges do not overlap. 
create two local networks on the azure.
Establish cross-site conectivity between Vnet to Vnet.
Use linc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-configure-vnet-to-vnet-connection/

create two VMs, one in each Vnet. 
Install AD DS on them. Also, install DNS on them with static IP.
Create users in the active directory of one of the VM. 
Establish communictation between the two VMs.
Users created in one VM get syced up in another VM.